# How to find where Java project/JAR's are locally on machine after a build?

Tags: java, build, jar

Where can I find the directory that my Java project places the JAR's after being built?

Comment: How do you build your jar?

Comment: *"Where can I find the directory that my Java project places"*  Browse your file system (probably starting at the root of the project).

Comment: @JigarJoshi +1 for environment-agnostic answer

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using NetBeans you'll need to "Clean and build" and it can then be found from the yourProjectName/dist folder.